# PostgreSQL can't insert data into table (column does not exist)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, string-constant

PostgreSQL 13, pgAdmin 4.

I have a table "Student" with the following columns:

- student_id (text, primary key)
- last_name (text)
- first_name (text)
- major (text)
- credit_hours (int)

I'm simply trying to add another student to this table, which I am attempting to do with the query below

```
INSERT INTO Public."Student" ("student_id", "last_name", "first_name", "major", "credit_hours")
VALUES ("S201217","BAR","FOO","CSC",100);
```

but when I run this query, I get this output

```
ERROR:  column "S201217" does not exist
LINE 2: VALUES ("S201217","BAR","FOO","CSC",100);
                ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 105
```

For such a basic error, I really must be missing something here, why is this query not able to add a row?

Answer (score 4):

Double quotes are used to quote columns. Use single quotation instead of double.

```
INSERT INTO Public."Student" ("student_id", "last_name", "first_name", "major", "credit_hours")
VALUES ('S201217','BAR','FOO','CSC',100);
```

Comment: This solved the issue lmao, thanks

Comment: Not only "in PostgreSQL" this is what the SQL standard requires.

Comment: @tanman,  if it answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1):

DB engine thinks this `"S201217"` is the column name, do single quotes and you'll be fine

```
INSERT INTO Public."Student" (student_id, last_name, first_name, major, credit_hours)
VALUES ('S201217','BAR','FOO','CSC',100);
```

You need "" if you using it for naming such has capitals of a break-in the string, for example, your table, as it starts with capital S it should be in double quotes, for column names no need it. or for example, if doing select

```
Select now() as 'Time now'
```

because alias has empty string and capital letter you need to include in ""

Comment: saved me so much pain, thank you